# How to remove numbers in a list that contain certain digits inside them

Tags: python-2.7

This is my code:

```
def second_test(numbers):
    for x in numbers:
        if 1 in x:
            numbers.remove(x)
        elif 7 in x:
            numbers.remove(x)
    print numbers

second_test(numbers)
```

`Numbers` is a list that contains int values from **10** to **1000**. I am trying to remove numbers within this range that contain either a 1 or a 7 in them. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to check if any digit of the number is a 1 or 7. There are two ways to do this:

The first way: Keep dividing the number by 10 and check the remainder (this is done with the modulus operator), until the number becomes 0

```
def check_num(n):
    while n:
        if n%10 == 1 or n%10 == 7:
            return True
        n /= 10
    return False


def second_test(numbers):
    to_delete = []
    for i,x in enumerate(numbers):
        if check_num(x):
            to_delete.append(i)
    for d in to_delete[::-1]:
        del numbers[d]
```

The second way: Turn the number into a string, and check each character of the string

```
def check_num(n):
    for char in str(n):
        if char=='1' or char=='7':
            return True
    return False

def second_test(numbers):
    to_delete = []
    for i,x in enumerate(numbers):
        if check_num(x):
            to_delete.append(i)
    for d in to_delete[::-1]:
        del numbers[d]
```

Comment: `check_num` can be done in a much cleaner/simpler way: `return {'1', '7'} <= set(str(n))`. If you don't like to use the set subset operator, you can still use `s = str(n); return '1' in s or '7' in s` instead of the Python loop.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: You're absolutely right. I was simply being super explicit (and using as few "tricks" as possible) to help out OP